# error sending data to server using volley library

Tags: android, android-volley

I have not used volley library much. i have read the tutorials. i want to send data to a url which which will enter that data in database. i have tried the following code but its not working. data is not entered in the database.

```
  String url = "http://tipseducation.com/system/eadmin/insertschedule/";
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //Valid Response
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //error message
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("appt_name", ed_name);
                params.put("appt_email", ed_email);
                params.put("appt_contact", ed_contact);
                params.put("appt_date", ed_date);
                params.put("appt_time", ed_time);
                params.put("appt_service", ed_spinner);
                return params;
            }
        };
```

can anyone please help me. iam new to this

Comment: Hey Can I make a call to your URL so that we can check if there is any entry added in database ?

Comment: @ Pri : Ohk so making a call...!!

Comment: Can i have sample of request data to send?

Comment: {"appt_email":"fdvg@fgvf.com","appt_service":"Test services 11","appt_contact":"8258936985","appt_time":"17.35","appt_name":"feybrg","appt_date":"15\/9\/2015"}

Comment: If you use POST your data should be in body.

Comment: @Pri : Status 200 OK and get HTML response contains message like 'Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/eadmin.php

Line Number: 21839'. So you should check your server..!!

Comment: @Mamata when i use Chrome Poster extension to test the data is entered succesfully. only through mobile application it is not sent

Comment: @Pri : Check output here..http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=0955847 !!

Comment: a service call generally consists of a backend php file name in url which I guess yours is not.

Comment: can you tell what is the file you intent to post data to

Comment: Does my answer work for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getHeaders`, you should use `getBody` for your POST request.

You can refer to my following working sample code (replace my `JSONObject` and Url by yours). Hope this helps!

```
        ...   
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("Title", "Android Volley POST DATA Demo");
            jsonBody.put("Author", "BNK");
            jsonBody.put("Date", "2015/09/17");
            requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(1, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // do something...
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // do something...
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            };
            queue.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ...
```