# Why Volley Send Cookie in Header Not Working Android?

Tags: android, cookies, header, android-volley

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.put("Authorization", Auth_token);
    headers.put("Cookie",  GlobleVariables.COOKIE_VALUE + Auth_token);
    return headers;
}
```

Comment: You need to add a lot more information please.  What do you want it to do, and what is it currently doing?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need compatibility with Android < 2.3 you just need to add this line of code in your onCreate of the activity or the application. That will activate default cookieManager for all httpURLconnections.

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
```

Source: [Volley ignores Cookie header request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645823/volley-ignores-cookie-header-request)

And you can find detail solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680701/using-cookies-with-android-volley-library)

Comment: add in app controller on create but still gives status code 422